# Webdriver manager ValueError: Could not get version for Chrome with this command

Tags: python, google-chrome, webdriver, webdriver-manager

It seems that webdriver manager always returns this error and I can figure why. I have carefully installed webdriver-manager but it still doesn't work...

Code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

And I get :

```
ValueError: Could not get version for Chrome with this command: reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\BLBeacon" /v version
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What’s version of Windows do you have? Your browser is GoogleChrome or Chromium? How did you install the browser - by installer from the official site or somehow specific?